# C++ program not reaching first line of main

Tags: c++, visual-studio, program-entry-point

This is `main.h`, I shared with you just in case there would be something wrong here.  But I don't think so.

Then, there is `main.cpp` which is the entry point of my program.
If I generate it with **Visual Studio 2017**, it will compile and run without errors but it will not print anything on the console.

I can't figure out why.

**main.h:**

```
#pragma once

#include <thread>

#include "GabEngine/MainEngine.h"
#include "GraphicInterface/Console.h"
#include "GabEngine/Globals.h"

int m_ScreenWidth = 500, m_ScreenHeight = 500;
GabEngine::Wind m_RootWindow;
GabEngine::MainEngine m_MainEngine(&m_RootWindow);
Globals::NetworkStatus NetStatus;
Networking::MainNetwork m_MainNetwork(&NetStatus);

void TaskConsole();
void TaskNetwork();
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "GraphicInterface/main.h"
#include <iostream>

#undef main

void TaskConsole()
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0)
    {
        GabEngine::FatalError("Failed to initialize SDL");
    }

    m_RootWindow.Create("Utryon", m_ScreenWidth, m_ScreenHeight, 2);
    m_MainEngine.InitShaders();
    m_MainEngine.InitCEGUI("C:/Users/Bob/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/Utryon/GabEngine/GUI");
    m_MainEngine.LoadScheme("UtryonLook.scheme");
    m_MainEngine.SetFont("DejaVuSans-10");

    GraphicInterface::Console MainConsole(&m_MainEngine, &m_MainNetwork);
    MainConsole.InitConsole();
    MainConsole.Run();
}

void TaskNetwork()
{
    m_MainNetwork.Run();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "Here 1" << std::endl;  //It is supposed to print Here 1
    thread ConsoleThread(TaskConsole);
    thread NetworkThread(TaskNetwork);

    ConsoleThread.join();
    NetworkThread.join();

    // End of program
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do you use #undef main?

Comment: one doubt: What is use of Command Line Argument i.e. argv ? I don't find it in code.

Comment: Implementations of functions 'ConsoleThread' and 'NetworkThread' must be  in main.cpp file.

Comment: One reason you might not be seeing any output is because the std::cout stream isn't being flushed. Try using std::cerr, which can be losely described as an 'auto-flushed std::cout'. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cerr/

Comment: And as @TigerTV.ru mentioned with function implementations, implementations of most multi-line functions should be kept in the .cpp files and leave prototyping to the .h files.

Comment: I use #undef main because there is a macro definition named main in SDL that generate a conflict otherwise.  I did the implementation of functions in .cpp files, thanks.  But it didn't solved the issue, std::cerr n either.  What could it be?  I mean how can something happen before the first line of main? It does not reach the first line...

Comment: The constructors of your global and static objects will execute before main() does.  Try putting printf/cout commands into the constructors of those objects; perhaps the execution is getting stuck in an infinite loop inside one of them, or something like that.

Comment: It is probably bombing out in one of your global variables or constructors of global variables. Before the first line of main() runs, the C and C++ runtime initialize global variables. Try setting breakpoints on your global variables and constructors of classes that have global instances. In my debugger (Visual C++), I can set to break whenever an exception is thrown. That is very handy.

Comment: Did you forget to include `#include <iostream>`, which contains `cout`, in your `main.cpp`?

Comment: @GabrielProulx *I mean how can something happen before the first line of main?* -- This is a fundamental of C++.  Global instances of classes have their constructors run before executing `main()`.

Comment: please have a better read mr n.m. This is not about sdl main

Comment: All evidence suggests that it is. If you have a conflict with SDL main, ask a question about the conflict (see [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). You probably won't see any console output in any case, because Windows subsystem programs don't use console by default.

Comment: If you insist on undrfining main anyway, you should probably try to use your debugger.

Comment: Do you compile your program as "Windows Application" (as opposed to "Console Application")? Windows applications don't show console by default.

Comment: Do not accept my last edition of the question.